# SQL Query Find Items With Two Criteria

Tags: sql, db2

I may be over thinking but this has me stumped, I have a table with items and want to display only items that appear more than once. For example, item 14295 is in the table twice once in company 1 and again in company 2. The field are FFIITMN item, FFIIDE1 description and FFICMPN company. I want to identify these so that we can have someone clean up this table. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT FFIITMN, FFIIDE1, FFICMPN
FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFIITMAP
WHERE FFICMPN = '  1' AND FFICMPN = '  2'
ORDER BY FFIITMN
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also specify the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see all items present in multiple companies (or in one but multiple times), you could use something like this:

```sql
select
    itm.*
FROM
    S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFIITMAP itm
    join (
        SELECT
            FFIITMN,
            count(*)
        FROM
            S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFIITMAP
        group by
            FFIITMN            
        Having
            count(*) > 1
    ) co on itm.FFIITMN = co.FFIITMN
    ORDER BY itm.FFIITMN, itm.FFICMPN
```

Here inner query selects all items that are multiple, and outer query selects this items with respective companies.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Column or global variable CC not found.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.72.44

Comment: @DanB. My bad - corrected

Answer (score 0):

The condition can not be true at a time
`FFICMPN = '1' AND FFICMPN = '2'`

To achieve :

> want to display only items that appear more than once. For example,
> item 14295 is in the table twice once in company 1 and again in
> company 2.

You should modify your query as below :

```
SELECT FFIITMN, FFIIDE1, FFICMPN, COUNT(*) AS occurrence_count
FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFIITMAP
WHERE FFICMPN IN ('1', '2')
GROUP BY FFIITMN, FFIIDE1, FFICMPN
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY FFIITMN;
```

If the item appears only once in both the companies; grouping by `FFICMPN` is not necessary.

```
SELECT FFIITMN, FFIIDE1, COUNT(*) AS occurrence_count
FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFIITMAP
WHERE FFICMPN IN ('1', '2')
GROUP BY FFIITMN, FFIIDE1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY FFIITMN;
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not returning any data and I have verified that there are at least two different repeated item numbers.